# How can I add 2 hours to a DateTime object (procedural style)?

Tags: php, date, datetime

Let's say I have to following code and I want to add 2 hours to the time. How can this be done?

```
<?php

    $start = '06:45:00';
    $startf = date_create_from_format('H:i:s', "$start");
    // add 2 hours to startf
    echo date_format($startf, 'H:i');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to use it is [`date_modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

```
$start = '06:45:00';
$startf = date_create_from_format('H:i:s', $start);
date_modify($startf , '+2 hours');
echo date_format($startf, 'H:i');
```

You can also use [`date_add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

```
$start = '06:45:00';
$startf = date_create_from_format('H:i:s', $start);
date_add($startf , date_interval_create_from_date_string('2 hours'));
echo date_format($startf, 'H:i');
```

Object oriented:

```
$start = '06:45:00';
$startf = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $start);
$startf->modify('+2 hours');
echo $startf->format('H:i');

$start = '06:45:00';
$startf = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $start);    
$startf->add(new DateInterval('PT2H'));
echo $startf->format('H:i');
```